# What are some polite responses to someone introducing themselves over the phone?

Tags: phrase-request, politeness

If a person comes up to you physically and then introduces themselves, your generic reply is going to be "Nice to meet you". It's not going to work in remote communications because you don't "meet" them, though. What are some polite responses to someone introducing themselves over the phone (or, say, Zoom)?

Comment: I suppose it would depend on _why_ they are contacting you. "Thank you for getting in touch" (if you had asked them to do so) - "How can I help you?" (if it was an unexpected call) etc. etc.

Comment: You can say "nice to meet you" even when "meeting" on Zoom (we literally call them "Zoom meetings"). Even by phone you can say "meet" and people will most likely understand what you mean.